# different layout portrait/landscape iOS 10 Autolayout Storyboard

Tags: iphone, xcode, autolayout, storyboard, ios10

Im’ new in auto layout with Storyboard in iOS 10 and I want to insert into in the View a button that In portrait mode its centered in the view and has a fixed width and height and for this reason I set right constraint and this works.

This is the screen on my situation :

[image]

My problem is this , I want to do this :

when device is in portrait mode button must have constrain that I described up(centered and fixed width and height) , but when device is in landscape mode I want that , for example , the button’s height is 400px.

How do I do this?

Comment: See size classes; if you pick a size class for (effectively) landscape mode, you can then add constraints specific to that size class, in the utilities area of Xcode. (Typically indicated by a (+) symbol in front of a setting.)

Comment: Can you explain better it? I’m new and I am confused

Comment: This is going to take a little time, and does require some reading, don't worry. You will also meet multipliers, e.g. "horizontally at two third of the distance from leading to trailing edge". And more very useful stuff. Really worth reading.

Comment: I found various reading but they are for iOS 9 and not for iOS 10. In them there isn’t “vary for traits” for example and I can’t follo it

Comment: I found this for example : https://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2014/08/working-with-size-classes-in-interface-builder/

Comment: but the Xcode steps in tutorial aren’t the same of my Xcode version

Comment: Apple lets Xcode evolve. One way to catch up is to look at release notes and watch the WWDC videos that apply (following a lecture of sorts). — Traits collections are somewhat recent. However, they still involve size classes in essential ways. "Adaptive Apps" is a search term. Apple's "Auto Layout Guide" is comprehensive and technical, and, at the risk of sounding boring, reading it takes time, too. Leave it opened.